# Sharing platform specific code - Uno platform

Tags: c#, webassembly, uno-platform

I'm studying Uno platform, and I would like to write my platform specific code in separate assemblies without using `#if` statements. I googled [this link](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/platform-specific-csharp.html) where they suggest using partial classes. Works fine but then I'd like to swap `FrameworkElement` depending on a platform. I followed this [tutorial](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/interop/wasm-javascript-3.html) and [this one](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/platform-specific-c-sharp-in-uno-platform-ios-android-wasm-uwp) and got this code for WASM head that is located in `.Shared` project:

```
[HtmlElement("input")] // Flatpickr requires an <input> HTML element
public partial class FlatpickrView : FrameworkElement
{
// *************************
// * Dependency Properties *
// *************************

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDateTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedDateTime", typeof(DateTimeOffset?), typeof(FlatpickrView), new PropertyMetadata(default(DateTimeOffset?)));

public DateTimeOffset? SelectedDateTime
{
    get => (DateTimeOffset)GetValue(SelectedDateTimeProperty);
    set => SetValue(SelectedDateTimeProperty, value);
}
//rest of the properties
}
```

To keep this code explicitly just for WASM I moved this file to `.WASM` project and added empty stub in `.Shared` project:

```
namespace FlatpickrDemo
{
    public partial class FlatpickrView : FrameworkElement
    {
    }
}
```

But the result is that when I'm starting project with WASM head no JavaScript is executed.
How do I effectively swap Control or Elements depending on a platform while keeping code in its respective head?